# DataTable.Merge Issue: Adds New Column (Due to Case Sensitivity)

Tags: c#, datatable

I am facing a strange issue with DataTable.Merge in development. I am trying to merge two tables into one. I am using the following code

```
gridData.Merge(existingGridData);
```

gridData has columns "PK", "A", "B", "AA", "BB" and existingGridData contains "PK", "A", "B", "C".

The merge result actually contains the following columns "PK", "A", "B", "AA", "BB", "A", "B", "C" (The columns are duplicated).

Any Idea? I also tried with

```
gridData.Merge(existingGridData, false, MissingSchemaAction.Ignore);
```

In this case, the primary key is not copied to the merge result and I am getting Constraint Violation exception.

My Table actually has extended properties (for Columns) and I also tried after copying the extended properties, so that two tables have same extended properties. I verified the Column Name, caption, DataType and all are same.

Two tables are constructed in different locations and have no previous relations.

I tried various scenarios in a new solution and it works fine.

Any help? Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Root Cause:** I found why it happened. I have changed the caption of the gridData to lowercase some where in code. In detail,  I fetched data from database. At that time the column name was in ALLCAPS, say "SAMPLEFIELD". Then in the following code, I renamed the column name (not caption) to "SampleField". The existingGridData also contained "SampleField". I expected both fields to be merged but its not.

When debugging through the .Net Framework Code, I found that there is a dictionary with Column Names (`Columns.columnFromName`), when you add Columns for the first time. But when you change the column name, this dictionary is not updated - if you provide the same column name with CAPS changed (but.. will be updated if its a different name).

This dictionary is used during Merge. Since the cases are changed it fails. Try the following code.

```
for (int i = 0; i < existingData.Columns.Count; i++)
{
    DataColumn src = existingData.Columns[i];

    DataColumn dest = (gridData.Columns.Contains(src.ColumnName)) ? gridData.Columns[src.ColumnName] : null;
    if (dest == null)
    {
         //You will get the column here
    }

    BindingFlags bindingFlags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic;
    MethodInfo minfo = typeof(DataColumnCollection).GetMethod("Contains", bindingFlags); //This override is used internally duting Merge

    var result = minfo.Invoke(gridData.Columns, new object[]{src.ColumnName, true});
    dest = ((bool)result) ? gridData.Columns[src.ColumnName] : null;                            

    if (dest == null)
    {
        //You wont get the column here. Its case sensitive                             
    }
}
```

Some other issues related to case sensitivity.
 http://forums.asp.net/t/707552.aspx

Hope this helps some one

Answer (score 0):

See below Code it is giving the correct output

```
DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
            dataTable.Columns.Add("PK");
            dataTable.Columns.Add("A");
            dataTable.Columns.Add("B");
            dataTable.Columns.Add("AA");
            dataTable.Columns.Add("BB");

            DataRow drRow = dataTable.NewRow();
            drRow[0] = 1;
            drRow[1] = 2;
            drRow[2] = 1;
            drRow[3] = 2;
            drRow[4] = 1;
            dataTable.Rows.Add(drRow);

            drRow = dataTable.NewRow();
            drRow[0] = 3;
            drRow[1] = 4;
            drRow[2] = 12;
            drRow[3] = 23;
            drRow[4] = 14;
            dataTable.Rows.Add(drRow);


            DataTable newTable = new DataTable();

            newTable.Columns.Add("PK");
            newTable.Columns.Add("A");
            newTable.Columns.Add("B");
            newTable.Columns.Add("C");

            newTable.ExtendedProperties.Add("TimeStamp",DateTime.Now);

            drRow = newTable.NewRow();
            drRow[0] = 5;
            drRow[1] =6;
            drRow[2] = 5;
            drRow[3] = 6;
            newTable.Rows.Add(drRow);

            drRow = newTable.NewRow();
            drRow[0] = 7;
            drRow[1] = 8;
            drRow[2] = 55;
            drRow[3] = 66;
            newTable.Rows.Add(drRow);

            dataTable.Merge(newTable,false);
```

Comment: I found the actual issue. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 methods which you can follow. Either you create the logic yourself, like what I am doing in the following method, or you can use inbuilt LINQ functions, like my second approach.

```
/// 
        /// This method is used to merge a set of data tables, based on common columns between them both
        /// 
        /// 
        /// 
        /// 
        public static DataTable MergeDataTables(DataTable dt1, DataTable dt2)
        {
            try
            {
                // Get common columns
                var commonColumns = dt1.Columns.OfType().Intersect(dt2.Columns.OfType(), new DataColumnComparer());

                // Create the result which is going to be sent to the user
                DataTable result = new DataTable();

                // Add all the columns from both tables
                result.Columns.AddRange(
                    dt1.Columns.OfType()
                    .Union(dt2.Columns.OfType(), new DataColumnComparer())
                    .Select(c => new DataColumn(c.Caption, c.DataType, c.Expression, c.ColumnMapping))
                    .ToArray());


                // Add the records of each data table to the new data table, based on the columns
                var rowData = dt1.AsEnumerable().Join(
                    dt2.AsEnumerable(),
                    row => commonColumns.Select(col => row[col.Caption]).ToArray(),
                    row => commonColumns.Select(col => row[col.Caption]).ToArray(),
                    (row1, row2) =>
                    {
                        var row = result.NewRow();
                        row.ItemArray = result.Columns.OfType().Select(col => row1.Table.Columns.Contains(col.Caption) ? row1[col.Caption] : row2[col.Caption]).ToArray();
                        return row;
                    },
                    new ObjectArrayComparer());

                // Loop and add
                foreach (var row in rowData)
                    result.Rows.Add(row);

                // Return result...
                return result;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("Problem while merging data tables. Check that there are common columns between the 2 data tables. Error : " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Or do the following;

```
// Results
                DataTable reportResult1 =  new DataTable(); // Your data table 1
                DataTable reportResult2 =  new DataTable(); // Your data table 2

                // Merge tables
                var commonColumns = reportResult1.Columns.OfType().Intersect(reportResult2.Columns.OfType(), new DataColumnComparer());

                // Remove DB Nulls, replace with empty strings
                reportResult1.RemoveColumnNulls(commonColumns.ToList());
                reportResult2.RemoveColumnNulls(commonColumns.ToList());

                reportResult1.PrimaryKey = commonColumns.ToArray();
                result.Merge(reportResult2, false, MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey);
                result.Merge(reportResult1, false, MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey);

                return result;
```

Let me know if you manage. I would go for option number 2, as it is much more optimised in terms of performance. What is done is the common columns between 2 tables are extracted, another table is created, and you will have a FULL OUTER JOIN effect. The common columns would be used as the JOINed columns.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. I changed all column names to upper case but still the issue was there. I took the default view of both tables and it fixed the issue. Anyway this will remove all the table expression. eg: column expressions.

So the steps was

1. Make sure all the columns are in same case.
2. Use default view of both table.
3. Additionally make sure all the columns has same max lengths. It may cause problems if exceeds the length.

   dataTable1 = dataTable1.DefaultView.ToTable();

   dataTable2 = dataTable2.DefaultView.ToTable();

   dataTable1 .Merge(dataTable2 , true, MissingSchemaAction.Add);